# SQLAlchemy: how to make relationship with custom primaryjoin on constant clause only

Tags: sqlalchemy

I try to improve the generic associations example [discriminator_on_association.py](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/bef93660c1b4a613d8545d6d04f9cac45254cd89/examples/generic_associations/discriminator_on_association.py?at=master) for using without any added new column to mixed model.

When I try to use relation like below:

```
relationship(assoc_cls,
             primaryjoin=foreign(remote(assoc_cls.discriminator))==discriminator)
```

I face with an error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not locate any simple equality
>   expressions involving locally mapped foreign key columns for primary
>   join condition 'address_association.discriminator = :discriminator_1'
>   on relationship Supplier.address_association.  Ensure that referencing
>   columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or
>   are annotated in the join condition with the foreign() annotation. To
>   allow comparison operators other than '==', the relationship can be
>   marked as viewonly=True.

How to set relationship to get the LEFT JOIN like below?

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_x 
       LEFT JOIN address_association ON address_association.discriminator='table_x'
```

Is it possible to set relationship to get the LEFT OUTER JOIN?

**UPDATE**:
The last source code version with property that I try use.

```
class BaseModelMixin(object):
    @db.declared_attr
    def fid(cls):
        return db.Column(db.Numeric(10,0), primary_key=True)

class Attr_type(BaseModelMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'attributes'

    fsname = db.Column(db.Unicode(128), index=True, nullable=False)
    fitype = db.Column(db.Numeric(5,0), nullable=False, default=200)
    _fstable = db.Column('fstable', db.String(64), index=True, nullable=True)

class Attr_value(BaseModelMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table_attrs'

    firec_id = db.Column(db.Numeric(10,0), index=True, nullable=False)
    fiattr_id = db.Column(db.Numeric(10,0), db.ForeignKey('attributes.fid', ondelete='CASCADE'), index=True, nullable=False)
    attr_type = db.relation("Attr_type", lazy="joined", uselist=False)
    fitype = db.association_proxy("attr_type", "fitype")
    _fstable = db.association_proxy("attr_type", "_fstable")
    value = db.Column(db.Unicode(255))

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class AttributesMixin(object):
    @property    
    def _table_attr_types(self):
        RowAttrVal = type("Attr_val_%s_%s" % (self.__tablename__, self.fid),
              (Attr_value, ),
              dict(
                   __mapper_args__ = {
                                      "polymorphic_on": "firec_id",
                                      "polymorphic_identity": self.fid
                                      }
                  )
              )

        TableAttrType = type("Attr_type_%s_%s" % (self.__tablename__, self.fid),
                         (Attr_type, ),
                         dict(
                              _values = db.relation(RowAttrVal,
                                                    uselist=False, 
                                                    ),
                              _value = db.association_proxy("_values", "value",
                              __mapper_args__ = {
                                                 "polymorphic_on": "_fstable",
                                                 "polymorphic_identity": self.__tablename__
                                                }
                              )
                         )

        return TableAttrType    

    def __new__(cls):        
        def get_attributes(self):
            return self._table_attr_types.query.all()

        def set_attributes(self, values):
            self._table_attr_types.query.set_by_jsons(values, decode=False)

        cls.attributes = property(get_attributes, set_attributes)

        return super(AttributesMixin, cls).__new__(cls)
```

**UPDATE 2**:
http://pastebin.com/YiX1ycNh - getter and setter property works, but expression does not

Comment: that join condition makes no sense.   it does not correspond to table_x in any way.

Comment: The sense which I mean is in having relation between table_x row and all address_association rows with some filter.

Comment: well you can use a @property that just loads everything from address_association.  It has no foreign key or other relationship to table_x so it's outside of what `relationship()` is intended for.  Every instance of "TableX" gets the exact same collection.

Comment: when I use the property I need to create a new type with polymorphic association at run time (it seems to me it's not pretty), but then another problem is here - values not returns correctly after the first request. However the first request returns correct values.

Comment: I struggle with this problem for a month and I cannot make proper and simple solution of Mixin like discriminator_on_association.py but without adding column to mixed Model.

Comment: sorry, I have no idea why you'd want to load an entire table of X, such that every instance of "table_x" gets the exact same collection, because there is no foreign key.  I don't understand why you need to make new association classes or anything else, or how you'd mutate this collection.  there seems to be no relationship between the two classes.

Comment: it is made with the purpose of having access to all types of possible attribute types for the table with capabilities to set attribute value for the model instance. When I jsonify Model instance I need to return all "attributes" available for this table and "values" specified for this attribute and instance. And vice versa when I load data to the Model.

Comment: I've many Models that have tablename and id primary key. I'd want to create Mixin which add the attribute as "attributes" through which I may access to create new "attribute", change "attribute" fields or delete attribute at all, and also to set/unset "value" for the "attribute" and instance of mixed Model with table "table_x". What solution you could suggest?

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, use the recipe in the examples as is, with a normal foreign key reference.   If you have myx = X(id=1), and you say, myx.attributes.append("some attribute"), you don't want some other X(id=5) to suddenly have "some attribute".

Comment: On the contrary, I want some other X(id=5) to have "some attribute" but not the value assigned to the "value" field

Comment: And I can't add new column and foreign key to previously unknown the Model to which Mixin will be applied.

Comment: I suppose there are no simple solution here.

Comment: can you confirm this is the sole effect you're looking for: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=BQbPPjCC

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this is the pattern you're looking for, but here's what so far it seems like.  In order to proxy to a regular @property, there's lots of ways to do that, here I repurposed _AssociationSet but this is just any Python setlike object with proxying behavior.

```py
from sqlalchemy import Integer, ForeignKey, Column, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Session, exc as orm_exc, \
    object_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import _AssociationSet
import operator

Base = declarative_base()


class ThingAssociationSet(_AssociationSet):
    def __init__(self, host):
        self.lazy_collection = lambda: host._attributes.attributes
        self.creator = lambda value: Attribute(value=value)
        self.getter = operator.attrgetter("value")

        def setter(target, value):
            target.value = value
        self.setter = setter
        self.parent = None


class HasThings(object):
    thing_type = None

    @property
    def _attributes(self):
        sess = object_session(self)
        if not sess:
            raise ValueError("attributes require shared session state")
        try:
            attrs = sess.query(AttributeCollection).\
                filter_by(type=self.thing_type).one()
        except orm_exc.NoResultFound:
            attrs = AttributeCollection(type=self.thing_type)
            sess.add(attrs)
        self.__dict__['attributes'] = attrs
        return attrs

    @property
    def attributes(self):
        return ThingAssociationSet(self)


class AttributeCollection(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'attr_collection'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    attributes = relationship("Attribute",
                    collection_class=set, cascade="all, delete-orphan")


class Attribute(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'attribute'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    collection_id = Column(ForeignKey('attr_collection.id'))
    value = Column(String(100), nullable=False)


class X(HasThings, Base):
    thing_type = 'x'
    __tablename__ = 'x'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class Y(HasThings, Base):
    thing_type = 'y'
    __tablename__ = 'y'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(e)

sess = Session(e)

x1 = X()
x2 = X()
x3 = X()
y1 = Y()
y2 = Y()

sess.add_all([x1, x2, x3, y1, y2])

x2.attributes.add("x attribute 1")
x3.attributes.add("x attribute 2")

y1.attributes.add("y attribute 1")

assert x3.attributes == set(["x attribute 1", "x attribute 2"])

x1.attributes.remove("x attribute 1")

assert x3.attributes == set(["x attribute 2"])
```

Comment: Thank you, Mike. This pattern is good. However, I've changed it with my needs http://pastebin.com/DxkecWH5 and have faced with the same problem that I cannot add attribute value to the record (model instance) without class mutation. The last thing I've done is using the property getter and setter with explicitly query joining and fields assigning http://pastebin.com/YiX1ycNh - it works, but may be you could see other better way.